# How can I make a ractive template with this Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I want to access all the property of this object.

```
var country = {
 country: "US",
 states : [{
    state: "california",
    capital: "sacramento"
    },
    {
    state: "texas"
    capital: "austin"
    }]
};
```

I tried the ff but only renders country value.

```
{{#each country}}
   {{country}}

   {{#each states}}
      {{states.state}} {{states.capital}}
   {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the part that's incorrect:

```html
{{#each states}}
  {{states.state}} {{states.capital}}
{{/each}}
```

Since `states` is an array, `states.state` doesn't mean anything – just use the property directly:

```html
{{#each states}}
  {{state}} {{capital}}
{{/each}}
```

As an aside, it's often a good idea to structure your data more like this:

```js
var country = {
  name: "US",
  states : [{
    name: "california",
    capital: "sacramento"
  },
  {
    name: "texas"
    capital: "austin"
  }]
};
```

In other words, the items in `states` are objects with `name` properties – the object *is* the state, it doesn't *have* a `state` property. I've often done that sort of thing in the past and come to regret it, because then you find confusing references to `state.state` in your code!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to iterate over `country` as if it were an array, but in your example that is only a plain object. In that case, this http://jsfiddle.net/ns8f8mwa/ will print that object. 
If you ment to first loop out every country, then the states, this http://jsfiddle.net/jgmbu7wr/ is an example of that.